# Text Split and Text Matching in c#

Tags: c#

Its very simple scenario in comparison of Text but i have been stuck in comparing of Two Text.
In C# I have created a function ***splitText*** which split the text into defined number of characters, then after that i assign the split text to a string variable and then compare to another string, but comparison does not work.

***Here is the splitText function***

```
private string splitText(string Text, int startingIndex, int totalCharacters)
        {
            string s = "";
            char[] str = new char[100];
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = startingIndex; i <= totalCharacters; i++)
            {
                str[count++] = Text[i];

            }
            s = new string(str);
            return s;
        }
```

***Here is the code where i compare the string but it does not work***

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = splitText("Khuram Jan", 0, 2);
            if (s.Equals("Khu"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I have done");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Does not compare");
            }
        }
```

I have also displayed the string ***s*** value , it shows me ***Khu***, but it does not work in if condition, alwys else portion executes. I tested alot but in vain to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code treats the variable named `totalCharacters`as if it would be `endIndex`. But the real issue is that you return a string of length 100, with first 3 characters `Khu`. Return `new string(str, 0, count)` instead.

Comment: but the issue is how to use a dynamic character array i-e char[] str = new str[totalCharacters] but it gives me exception.

Comment: Thanks alot Remus Rusano for helping me, now it works,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, you are not getting exact chart length string return value. In your case you are returning "Khu\0\0\0...."

Modified line is

```
char[] str = new char[totalCharacters+1];
```

By the way, you can use following too!

```
 string s1 = "Khuram Jan".Substring(0, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i understand where i was doing mistake, thansks for your value able comments